# Parameterized type converts Char to Int

Tags: scala

I accidentally noticed the following:

```
scala> class g[T](val x:T)   
defined class g

scala> val obj=new g[Int]('A')
obj: g[Int] = g@1082d45

scala> obj.x
res6: Int = 65
```

What is happening here? A typecast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's upconversion of primitives.  Primitive values will convert themselves to the next numerically-larger type if it seems like that is needed.  So `val s: Short = (0: Byte)` works.  Nothing converts to `Char`, but `Char` will become an `Int`, `Long`, `Float`, or `Double` if it needs to to be the right argument type.

The reason this is done is mostly because it's how Java does it, but partly because getting an error off of `val d: Double = 0` is really annoying since `0` of course fits into a `Double` with no problems whatsoever, and there's no ambiguity about the type either.

Answer (score 2):

See also:

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/1c8add14605c4c6e818693d0d9c653407ab69837/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L319

The following implicit conversion is enabled by default.

```
implicit def char2int(x: Char): Int = x.toInt
```

In this case, the expected type is `Int`. So the `Char` value is converted.